# Minimizing basic boolean function

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

$==============================$
Given the function $f(x,y,z) = y'z'+x'y+x'yz+xyz'$
(where ' means the NOT operator), I need to transfer this function to its basics. The possible answers are:

1. $x'y+y'z'$
2. $xy+z'$
3. $x'y'+z'$
4. $x'y+z'$

This is what I've done. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. It's not in the answers....

$\begin{align}
F(x\,,y\,,z)&=\overline{y}\overline{z}+\overline{x}y+\overline{x}yz+xy\overline{z}\\
&=\overline{y}\overline{z}+\overline{x}y(1+z)+xy\overline{z}\\
&=\overline{y}\overline{z}+\overline{x}y+xy\overline{z}\\
&=(x+\overline{x})\overline{y}\overline{z}+\overline{x}y(z+\overline{z})+xy\overline{z}\\
&=x\overline{y}\overline{z}+\overline{x}\overline{y}\overline{z}+\overline{x}yz+\overline{x}y\overline{z}+xy\overline{z}\\
&=x\overline{z}+\overline{x}\overline{z}+\overline{x}yz\\
&=\overline{z}+\overline{x}yz
\end{align}$

Comment: You should start to format your posts: [Markdown Help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11206)

Comment: I don't think that this is called "minimizing a boolean function" but you try to "simplify a boolean expression" or you try to find an equivalent expression that is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\\
& y'z'+x'y+x'yz+xyz'\\
&=y'z'+x'y(1+z)+xyz'\\
&=y'z'+x'y+xyz'\\
&=y'z'+(x'+xz')y\\
&=y'z'+(x'+z')y\\
&=y'z'+x'y+yz'\\
&=(y+y')z'+x'y\\
&=z'+x'y
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are very close! To finish up, note that $$\bar z=\bar z(1+\bar x y),$$ from which you should see that answer 4 is correct.